# Laurent series , function representation

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, laurent-series

Write the Laurent series around zero for the entire function $f(z)=z^2e^{3z}$

I'm a little confused on how to represent the complex functions by series, as I did in the calculation of real functions, but do not know if it's right

$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\rightarrow e^{3z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^nz^n}{n!}\rightarrow z^2e^{3z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^nz^{n+2}}{n!}$$

ii) Find the Laurent series representation for $f(z)=z^2\sin(\frac{1}{z^2})$ where $0<|z|<\infty$

Comment: should be $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{3^nz^{n+2}}{n!}$

Comment: You may write $$z^2e^{3z}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{3^{n-2}z^{n}}{(n-2)!}$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa But my answer is correct? The procedure to find the representation of a complex function is the same as real functions?

Comment: @askazy Your procedure and your result are correct.

Comment: @OlivierOloa My biggest question is when there is a restriction on z, take a look at what added kindly.

Comment: @askazy OK, let me give an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second part, you may write
$$
\sin\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!\:z^{2(2n+1)}},\quad z \neq0,
$$ giving
$$
f(z)=z^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!\:z^{4n}},\quad z \neq0.
$$ since $\displaystyle u \longmapsto \sin(u) $ has a power series with an **infinite** radius of convergence.